# Cordova File-transfer plugin not responding with XDK platform

Tags: jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins, file-transfer, intel-xdk

I am trying to upload a video to back end service using File-transfer plugin and XDK development Platform

- Testing on Android Lollipop system and XDK emulator.
- My system is windows 7
- XDK version is: 2893

My Code is

```
function uploadVideo(){
        alert("button Clicked");

    var url = '';
    var filePath = Uservideo.videoPath;
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(url);

     var params = {filename: Uservideo.videoPath,
                 category_id:"1",
                 about:"whatever",
                 access_token:userHandler.login_token};

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.httpMethod="POST";
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = Uservideo.videoPath.substr(Uservideo.videoPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
    options.params = params;

        alert(JSON.stringify(options));
        alert(filePath);
        console.log("filePath: "+filePath);

    fileTransfer.upload(filePath,
        url,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("upload complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        alert("success"+entry);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        },options);
}
```

The issue is I am trying to debug and find how the function reacts in my application but i never got an error or a success response from the back-end or the debugger, the function is not even seen i guess

A friend used my code and run it using phonegap terminal and claimed that it worked fine with him."am not sure"

I just can't determine where's the issue
is it XDK?
is it the plugin itself?
is it my way of implementing the code?
is it the back-end service?

Help Am STUCK

Comment: are you testing in XDK emulator?

Comment: No a real android device with lollipop os

Comment: most likely backend service, whats the url ?

Comment: is that ethical am doing it for a company :/

Comment: i did tested the service url and it worked perfectly using Postman desktop app, am not pretty sure that the backend can actually understand the file format or something, provide me with a personal contact to send you the urls and access token

Comment: what error are u getting ?

Comment: when using normal jquery post function am retreiving status 200 Ok, but i get a message that you didn't chose a file to upload although the file path is exactly as it is on the mobile phone

....... but when using file transfer plugin the function acts like a ghost, neither error not success responses are retrieved or appeared in the app log